# Clearing lru_cache of certain methods when an attribute of the class is updated?

Tags: python, caching, synchronization, functools, lru

I have an object with a method/property `multiplier`. This method is called many times in my program, so I've decided to use `lru_cache()` on it to improve the execution speed. As expected, it is much faster:

The following code shows the problem:

```
from functools import lru_cache

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_contract = 201706
        self.futures = {201706: {'multiplier': 1000},
                        201712: {'multiplier': 25}}

    @property
    @lru_cache()
    def multiplier(self):
        return self.futures[self.current_contract]['multiplier']

CF = MyClass()
assert CF.multiplier == 1000

CF.current_contract = 201712
assert CF.multiplier == 25
```

The 2nd `assert` fails, because the cached value is 1000 as `lru_cache()` is unaware that the underlying attribute `current_contract` was changed.

Is there a way to clear the cache when self.current_contract is updated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes quite simply: make `current_contract` a read/write property and clear the cache in the property's setter:

```
from functools import lru_cache

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.futures = {201706: {'multiplier': 1000},
                        201712: {'multiplier': 25}}
        self.current_contract = 201706

    @property
    def current_contract(self):
        return self._current_contract

    @current_contract.setter
    def current_contract(self, value):
        self._current_contract = value
        type(self).multiplier.fget.cache_clear()

    @property
    @lru_cache()
    def multiplier(self):
        return self.futures[self.current_contract]['multiplier']
```

NB : I assume your real use case involves costly computations instead of a mere dict lookup - else `lru_cache` might be a bit overkill ;)

Comment: Actually it's really a mere dict lookup, but it's called hundreds of thousands times in my program and using lru_cache made a big difference. I'll test it again with the new code.

Many thanks for your help! It solved the problem.

Comment: If you have such a need for optimizations you may want to use `self._current_contract` instead of `self.current_contract` in `multiplier` (to avoid the property call / method call / attribute resolution overhead), and possibly just make multiplier a plain attribute that gets set in `current_contract` setter (note that I haven't done any benchmarking so you may want to `timeit` first to find out which solution is indeed the fastest)

Comment: That's what I did, will test it soon. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers can you please give me some color on why you have to use `type(self).multiplier.fget.cache_clear()` instead of `self.multiplier.fget.cache_clear()` ? thx

Comment: Because else you'd trigger the property mechanism. You can read the official doc about descriptors (the general mechanism that supports computed attributes) to get the details.

Comment: Hi everyone! Is there a way to clear the `lru_cache` for only one instance of the class? I mean suppose the changes on attributes of one object require a cache flush, but another object doesn't requires a cache flush. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

### Short Answer

Don't clear the cache when `self.current_contract` is updated.  That is working against the cache and throws away information.

Instead, just add methods for `__eq__` and `__hash__`.  That will teach the cache (or any other mapping) which attributes are important for influencing the result.

### Worked out example

Here we add `__eq__` and `__hash__` to your code.  That tells the cache (or any other mapping) that *current_contract* is the relevant independent variable:

```
from functools import lru_cache

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_contract = 201706
        self.futures = {201706: {'multiplier': 1000},
                        201712: {'multiplier': 25}}

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.current_contract)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.current_contract == other.current_contract

    @property
    @lru_cache()
    def multiplier(self):
        return self.futures[self.current_contract]['multiplier']
```

An immediate advantage is that as you switch between contract numbers, previous results are kept in the cache.  Try switching between 201706 and 201712 a hundred times and you will get 98 cache hits and 2 cache misses:

```
cf = MyClass()
for i in range(50):
    cf.current_contract = 201712
    assert cf.multiplier == 25
    cf.current_contract = 201706 
    assert cf.multiplier == 1000
print(vars(MyClass)['multiplier'].fget.cache_info())
```

This prints:

```
CacheInfo(hits=98, misses=2, maxsize=128, currsize=2)
```